# R - Combine and split large data.frames

Tags: r, data.table

I have two very large data.frames (each has > 100,000 rows) that I am trying to run analyses on.  They are too big to run my code efficiently, so I'm looking for an efficient way to break them into smaller sets.

Sample Data Frames 1 & 2 (as data.table objects)

1)

```
Sample     Chr    Value   Pop
1          1       100     X
1          2       200     X
2          1       100     X
2          2       200     X
```

2)

```
Sample     Chr    Value   Pop
3          1       300     Y
3          2       200     Y
4          1       100     Y
4          2       400     Y
```

I'd like to both COMBINE the two AND split them by `Chr` column.  The final list would look like this:

```
toydata
$`1`
Sample     Chr    Value   Pop
1          1       100     X
2          1       100     X
3          1       300     Y
4          1       100     Y
$`2`
Sample     Chr    Value   Pop
1          2       200     X
2          2       200     X
3          2       200     Y
4          2       400     Y
```

**My work so far**

So far, I know I can combine data.frames by the following:

```
newdf <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

And I can split the data.frames by using `split()` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
newdf <- split(newdf, as.factor(newdf$Chr), drop=TRUE)
```

Then I can run any downstream analysis:

```
lapply(newdf, somefunction)
```

However, this is just too much for my computer.  I assume if I could SPLIT FIRST and then combine, it might be better, but I'm also open to other time and processor friendly solutions.

Worst case scenario, I know I can just subset each `Chr` into its own data.frame and do the analysis for each of these, but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html

Comment: `split()` is from `base`, not `data.table`.

Comment: @Stibu There is another version of split() in data.table, which I am using (could be in the developer version, as that's the version I'm using).  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/9d2d71098d849c99e6eebb0e0b539eb58d723b05/man/split.Rd

Comment: Depending on how close your combined dataset is to your memory limit, you might try the following: bind the data, save to disk, close R and all other programs, open R, try to split the dataset.

Comment: Assuming that you are working with csv file, you can restrict how many rows it can read while reading it to R. For example for your data you can make 10 files each containing 10,000 rows. `file_1 <- read.csv("mydata.csv", nrows=1:10000), file_2 <- read.csv("mydata.csv", nrows=10001:20000) etc `. Hope it helps!

Comment: @BoroDega Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, I need to do my analyses on subset, which doesn't correspond with rows.  I have 22 `Chr`s, so I'd need 22 subsets and then need to do my full analysis 22 times.  If that's the only/best way, fine, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @Stibu fyi: [split manual](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/split.html) from data.table 1.9.7

Comment: @GaiusAugustus `split(newdf, by="Chr", drop=TRUE)` this would be faster equivalent of split call from your question. Of course `newdf` must be a data.table class to be picked up by `split.data.table` method.

Comment: @jangorecki I am aware of that. But as you say, this is a Methode for data tables and the OP was using data frames. He was therefore using the method from base.

Answer (score 2):

You want the amazing **data.table** package, but it sounds like you have some reading to do before you will be able to use its full capabilities, which for you means the `by =` argument.  100,000 rows is nothing to **data.table**.

Selecting subsets is easy and fast.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(rbind(df1, df2))
dt
##    Sample Chr Value Pop
## 1:      1   1   100   X
## 2:      1   2   200   X
## 3:      2   1   100   X
## 4:      2   2   200   X
## 5:      3   1   300   Y
## 6:      3   2   200   Y
## 7:      4   1   100   Y
## 8:      4   2   400   Y

# extract a subset
dt[Chr == 1]
##    Sample Chr Value Pop
## 1:      1   1   100   X
## 2:      2   1   100   X
## 3:      3   1   300   Y
## 4:      4   1   100   Y
```

Applying functions to groups is just as easy, and no splitting is necessary.

```
# apply a function to a group
somefunction <- mean
dt[, somefunction(Value), by = Chr]
##    Chr  V1
## 1:   1 150
## 2:   2 250
```